# Bottom Navegation View

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, navigationbar

When I put in the XML with its attributes, it doesn't appear in the design part, I don't know if something is happening, because it instantiated all the dependencies that were needed.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">  </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

and dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
```

They are all the dependencies that I use and the image that shows me the design is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZSQ9.png)

I don't see any navigation bar or any error, I don't know what to do, help pls.

Answer (score 0):

remove this 2 dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'
```

and replace them with this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

try to use also this code

layout resource file:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
 </menu>
```